# Data push into array overwrites values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to pass an array to a function and convert the numeric date.

E.g.: `2020-02-29` converted to `29th February 2020 (Saturday)`.

My code is below. When I am trying to push the converted date to array, the previous value get overwritten. I have gone through many articles on StackOverflow, but didn't find any best solution for it. I have created a new local array before pushing the same one (the same reference) each time, but the problem still persist.

Could you suggest me a better solution for my problem statement OR should I do some modification in the existing code?

Array data as input:

```
var data = ['2020-02-29', '2020-03-01', '2020-03-02'];
```

Start of a function:

```
function getFullName(data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var d = new Date(data[i]);
        var date = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var dayName = d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });

        function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
            var j = (i % 10);
            k = (i % 100);
            if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
                return i + "st";
            }
            if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
                return i + "nd";
            }
            if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
                return i + "rd";
            }
            return i + "th";
        }
        var pdate = ordinal_suffix_of(date);

        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];
        var result = [];
        var pmonth = monthNames[month];
        var response = pdate + ' ' + pmonth + ' ' + year + ' (' + dayName + ')';
        result.push(response);
        console.log(result);
    }
     return result;
};
```

Calling function:

```
getFullName(data);
```

Comment: It is not the push who overwrites your data but it is response = because you store the variable response in your result array and you change the variable value also you write result = [] everytime you call the function which resets result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a minor issue with the code, your `result` variable must be defined outside the loop:

```js
// Array data as input

var data = ['2020-02-29', '2020-03-01', '2020-03-02'];

// Start of a function

function getFullName(data) {
    var result = []; // Define here
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var d = new Date(data[i]);
        var date = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var dayName = d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });

        function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
            var j = (i % 10);
            k = (i % 100);
            if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
                return i + "st";
            }
            if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
                return i + "nd";
            }
            if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
                return i + "rd";
            }
            return i + "th";
        }
        var pdate = ordinal_suffix_of(date);

        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];
        var pmonth = monthNames[month];
        var response = pdate + ' ' + pmonth + ' ' + year + ' (' + dayName + ')';
        result.push(response);
    }
     return result;
};

// Calling function 

console.log(getFullName(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `var result = [];` declaration before `for` loop, because `result` is overwritten in every iteration

```js
function broken() {
  for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    var result = [];
    result.push(i)
  }
  return result;
}

function fixed() {
  var result = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {  
    result.push(i)
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(broken());
console.log(fixed());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are initializing your `var result = []` within the `for(...){}`, your result gets "wiped out" and creates a new array every iteration of your `for loop`

you can solve the problem by moving `var result = []` to the outside of your `getFullName` function OR move it outside of `for loop`

p.s. This looks like you need to understand more about what `lexical scope` is in javascript. I suggest doing some research into the high-level concept of lexical scopes.